# Rails partial caching is showing view changes despite no model changes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, caching

Following the guide from "Agile Web Development with Rails 4."
It covers caching for a product catalog to only re-render products that changed.

I edited (config/environments/development.rb):

```
config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
```

Added code to return most recently updated product:
(app/models/product.rb)

```
def self.latest
  Product.order(:updated_at).latest
end
```

Lastly updated the store index for the cache:
(app/views/store/index.html.erb)

```
<h1>Your Pragmatic Catalog</h1>
<% cache ['store', Product.latest] do %>
  <% @products.each do |product| %>
    <% cache ['entry', product] do %>
      <div class="entry">
        <%= image_tag(product.image_url) %>
        <h3><%= product.title %></h3>
        <%= sanitize(product.description) %>
        <div class="price_line">
          <span class="price"><%= number_to_currency(product.price) %></span>
        </div>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

The book states the only way to test if caching is working is to change the view so all I did was add some lorem ipsum within one or both cache tags but the browser immediately shows the change on refresh... Frustrating! Any clue?

Comment: You've got a bug on `Product.latest`, that's calling itself. You probable have a `Product.order(:updated_at).last(10)` there if no error arises.

Comment: may be obvious, but have you restarted your server after changing environment file?

Answer (score 1):

try using

```
<% cache ['v1', Product.order(updated_at: :desc).last] do %>
```

instead of

```
<% cache ['store', Product.latest] do %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your cache key for the collection is not changing. That happens because `cache ['store', Product.latest]` is not as clever as you expect. If you have a look at the log you'll see that the cache key that was used is a literal including something like *ActiveRecord::Relation::Products*.

Use the last *updated_at* value `cache ['store', Product.latest.max(:updated_at)]` for better results.

In Rails 5 this will be easier due to [the addition of `cache_key` to ActiveRecord::Relation](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/20884) a few weeks ago.